Why does Rashi switch the order that Onkelos uses when describing the people of S'dom's sins?
In Bereishis 13:13 it says:

ואנשי סדום רעים וחטאים לה' מאוד

Onkelos translates as follows:

ואנשין דסדום בישין בממונהון וחייבין בגביתהון קדם ה' לחדא
The people of S'dom were wicked with their property and sinful with their bodies towards Hashem, exceedingly.

Meaning, he takes רעים to mean monetary sins, and חטאים to mean bodily sins.
Rashi, on the other hand, explains the opposite way around:

רעים בגופם: וחטאים בממונם:
Wicked in their persons: and sinners with their wealth:

Why does Rashi explain the sins attributed to these words the opposite of how Onkelos does?

He cites Sanhedrin, not Onkelos

Onkelos cites Tosefta Sanhedrin 13:8 (from smaller sin to bigger), Rashi cites Gemara Sanhedrin 109a which better fits the language of the verse as explained in Parshegen by R' Posen.

Sanhedrin 109a has both possibilities

@YDJ look at Parshegen again he's not saying that

Thanks to shmosel for pointing me in the right direction

The gemara in Sanhedrin (109a) actually brings both versions. As the Gur Aryeh explains (on the Rashi quoted in my question):

רעים בגופם וכו' והתרגום תרגם איפכא. ובפרק חלק (סנהדרין קט.) איכא ברייתא כדברי המתרגם ורב יודא כדברי רש"י. ויראה לי דטעם הברייתא דיותר יש לקרות 'רע' מי שהוא חוטא בממון, כדכתיב "ורעה עיניך וגו'", ודבר זה מורה שיש בו רע עין, מאחר שאינו עושה טוב לאחר. ולדעת רב יודא 'רעים בגופם' לפי ש'רע' הוא יותר מן 'חטא', לפי שהוא רע לגמרי, ולפיכך יש לומר 'רעים בגופם' והוא יותר רע ממי שחוטא בממון, שזה נקרא 'חוטא'. ותפס רש"י דברי רב יודא, כי יותר לפי פשוטו שנקרא 'רע' מי שגופו רע.
Wicked in their persons etc. Yet Onkelos translated the opposite. In chapter Chelek (Sanhedrin 109a) there is a b'raisa like Onkelos' version, and Rav Yehuda like Rashi's. And it seems to me that the reasoning of the b'raisa is that it is more accurate to call 'evil' one who sins monetarily, because the passuk states "and your eye is evil (towards your poor brother, and you don't give him charity)", and this shows that this man has an evil eye, because he doesn't do good to others. And Rav Yehuda holds that it means 'evil with their bodies' because 'evil' is worse than 'sinner', because he is completely bad, therefore it makes more sense to say 'evil with their bodies' which is worse than sinning monetarily, which is therefore only called 'a sinner'. And Rashi chose to go according to Rav Yehuda, because it follows the p'shat explanation that one whose body is evil, is evil.

